# Login loop for the website teams.microsoft.com

Tags: windows-8.1, browser, login, skype, office365

On a system with:

- Win8.1
- Office 2010 Home / Student
- Firefox, IE11, Chrome
- Skype

with none of the browsers it's possible to logon to the teams.microsoft.com website. I always had a white login screen titled checking your credentials in a loop. How can this problem be solved?

I have tried several solutions:

- deleting the cookies in the browsers
- set entries for `Internet Options` → `Security` → `Trusted Sites`
- logoff from any Office application

Comment: It took me two days I hope it helps others too.

Comment: Please post your answer *as an answer* (in the ‘‘**Your Answer**’’ box).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, the following worked.
Since it worked without problems in another system with Office 2016 and Skype for business the solution was:

- Uninstall Skype
- Install Skype for business
- Time synchronization